# Lighting doesn't affect anything

Tags: rendering, lighting

So i've made a model and assigned materials to it, and I have a sun lamp up. When I render it the lighting doesn't render what so ever. It's like I have none there and it's all ambient. Changing the scale and strength of the light changes nothing. Scales have all been normalised as I've seen that's something that affects it. I just can't get it to work.

Comment: Welcome, Ben. Make sure the mesh and the light are in the same layer.

Comment: That seems to be the problem, how do I get them all on the same layer? When i hit M it says Move out of local view instead of move to layer like im used to

Comment: You're in local view. Press /.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. I don't even know how I got into local view (dont even know what it's for) since I dont have a number pad, says the hotkey is on that.

Comment: Local view is to isolate an object for better manipulation especially when editing the meshes.